# Assign class name dynamically loop in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to add a class name dynamically from 1 to 10 to a button. Means it will show class1, class2 ... class10. How can I do this?

Comment: How can you do this? You can do it by googling your question, reading some documentation, then using the IDE of your choice, writing some code. If you do this and still can't figure it out, you can ask a question here that is thoughtful, clear, and shows that you've put some effort into it. Then, maybe someone will provide you with some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this way:

```
<% (1..10).each do |i| %>
 <button class='<%= "class#{i}"%>'></button>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This code generating 10 buttons. for each div. means 100 buttons on pages.

Comment: @Sumeet you are not mentioned any details in above quesion just ask for genrating dynamic class for button. not mentioned any div and other details. so firstly correct your quesion.

Comment: Hey, sorry for that. I have a main for each loop in that I have added that code. But if I remove your code from for each loop it works. Thanks.

Comment: Ok if this code is useful to you then just accept the answer

Comment: just a small advice @sumeet it would be better if you move this iterations to some method in helper and call it in your view.Note: Its better to keep things like iterations out of the views.